# Divide polyline in overlapping segments

Tags: qgis

Imagine I have a single polyline and I want to divide it, but not exactly split.

I want to have a "step" and a "length", and create segments that overlap. Each segment starting "step" meters further from the start of the previous segment, and each segment with the same "length", like in the picture:

[image]

(In the picture, I made the lines visible, but in fact they overlap)

Does QGIS have a simple function for doing so? (Coding is possible but not preferred)

Comment: Please decide which software you want to use.

Comment: Any of them is fine

Comment: Linear referencing does this

Answer (score 0):

If you use QGIS to divide the polyline into equal spaced vertices. The spacing should be 1/2 of the overlap distance.  Then collect the vertices in each new (shorter line) with respect to the sum of the vertices distance will be the new line length + 1 vertex. Then turn those into new polylines.

- QGIS Processing toolbox => Points along geometry.

  - Select the line
  - Choose the vertex spacing.
- QGIS Processing toolbox => Points to path.

  - Select the number of points that gets to the length you require.
  - Repeat this and select the correct number of points until the end point is consumed.

If you have a bunch of these, you should probably use code inside of QGIS.
You use the same algorithm as the "Points Along Geometry" to get all of the required vertices.  Determine the number of vertices that will make the correct length (n). Then loop through these and keep appending points to a line until n + 1 and start a new line with n - 1

Comment: This would require that "length" is a multiple of "step", which may not be the case. It also disregards the original line vertices which will change the geometry.

Comment: It will e easier if you want to use only original vertices, just skip the Points along geometry step.  Did you want to interpolate the overlap point or use the original vertex that is closest to the length?